# Ideals in a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image: I couldn't type the question easily so I added a picture of it.]

I completed part a with no problems using the ideal test. However it is part b that is giving me troubles. I'm not sure where to start with this one, any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can give an explicit description of $e_{ii}R$, then if $A$ is an ideal contained in $e_{ii}R$ it's elements must have the same form of those in $e_{ii}R$. take a non zero element $X \in A$. A is a right ideal so you can multiply it by a convenient matrix $B \in R$ (hint: such $B$ only have one non zero column) such that $XB$ is a multiple of $e_{ii}$.